# How to use generalized additive models where all the functions to estimate are the same?

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, generalized-additive-model, splines

I've this kind of equation that I'd like to estimate using R :

$t_i = \alpha_1 f(x_{1i}, y_{1i})+\alpha_2 f(x_{2i},y_{2i})+\epsilon_i$.

$t_i \in [0,1]$. $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are known. I observe $x_{1i}, x_{2i}, y_{1i}$ and $y_{2i}$. I'm not sure of the best way to estimate this model. I thought about generalized additive models, but I've two problems : the estimated $f$ will be different and I want them to be exactly the same, and also I want $f$ to be multivariate. Maybe there's a way to add some constraints on gam regressions with R to force the functions to be the same, but I absolutely don't know how to do that.

I also thought of using an answer similar to the one given on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752550/defining-gam-function-type), but I'm not sure that this solution is adapted to estimate a multivariate function.

If anyone has an idea or some code that might help, I would very much enjoy it

EDIT : $t_i$ is between 0 and 1 as it's a proportion by definition. The $\alpha_i$ are weights and some to 1. And $f(x_{ji}, y_{ji}) \in [0,1]$ by definition, it represents a probability :
$f(x_{ji}, y_{ji})=\mathbb{P}(\nu_i>k+g(x_{ji}, y_{ji}))$ where $k$ is an unknown constant not depending on $i$, $\nu_i$ can be assumed to follow a normal distribution, $g(x_{ji}, y_{ji})$ is unknown. $x_i$ and $y_i$ are positive (not strictly), by definition. $g$ does not depend on $j$, neither on $i$ or $j$.

Comment: I think you should say a bit more about *why* you know $t_i \in [0,1]$. Is this something that just happens to be true for your data set, or is it a constraint imposed by the definition of $t_i$, for example are they probabilities or proportions? Similarly, is there anything we should know about $\alpha_i$, for example are they weights that sum to one? It would be best to edit this into the question rather than reply in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question according to your questions. Don't hesitate to ask precisions if I'm not totally clear